# Diophantine equations $a^2+b^2+k=c^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

If $k=0$ then equation $a^2+b^2=c^2$ has an infinite number of solutions in integers.

But is something special about the case $k=0$?

In other words, suppose that we choose some $k \in \mathbb Z$ and try to determine when $a^2+b^2+k=c^2$ has an infinite number of solutions.

Is it true that for every $k \in \mathbb Z$ there is an infinite number of integer triples $(a,b,c)$ which are solutions of $a^2+b^2+k=c^2$?

Comment: If I had time I'd try setting $k=-2ab \cos C$ such that $C=\pi/3$ and seeing what you come up with

Comment: Ante, as I said yesterday,  you should learn some easy computer language, these days Python is a good bet. Then learn how to write successful programs. This is helpful for "elementary" number theory questions, and will give you interesting data to include with your questions.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, for any $k$, there are infinite many integer solutions.

For any odd number $\ell$, $k + (k+\ell)^2$ is odd. You can verify following 3 integers

$$(a,b,c) = \left( k+\ell, \frac{k + (k+\ell)^2 - 1}{2}, \frac{k + (k+\ell)^2+1}{2} \right)$$
satisfies $a^2 + b^2 + k = c^2$